# How do people shave in the Galaxy Far, Far Away?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Related to [How do people shave in the 24th century?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/141093/13217) (regarding *Star Trek*), how do people shave in the Galaxy Far, Far Away (i.e. the *Star Wars* universe)? Do they use traditional razors? Do they have any fancy sci-fi devices that do it for them? Or do they have *lightshavers* [as *Robot Chicken* suggests](https://youtu.be/PZFCqS6B-wo?t=13s)?

[image]

I'm open to answers in either canon or Legends, so long as they are clearly marked as such (and would prefer an answer that includes both, if applicable).

Comment: Real men in the Galaxy Far, Far Away only shave with their lighshabers.

Comment: Or they just stay as scruffy-looking nerf-herders.

Comment: @Loki Thanks for reminding me that Robot Chicken went with that idea :-) I think that *Jedi Knight: Dark Forces II* also had Kyle Katarn trying to shave with his lightsaber as an idle animation.

Comment: http://starwars.omegacron.com/images/temp/fett-shaving.jpg

Comment: Force saves and shaves!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Canon

In an episode of *The Clone Wars* CG-animated show, we see Obi-Wan get shaved by what appears to be magic:

It's not quite clear what the medical droid is doing, only that it doesn't sound like a shaving device we would recognize, and that it completely disintegrates his hair and beard.

At least some members of the galactic community still use traditional razors; Galen specifically asks for one while being held captive on Vallt:

> "I am Chieftain Gruppe. Have you been comfortable? Is there anything you need?"
>
> Galen rubbed the growth that covered his cheeks and chin. "A razor. A hot bath. An extra blanket."
>
> <sup>*Catalyst: A Rogue One Novel* Chapter 2: "Isolation"</sup>

### Legends

Razors appear to still exist, but [depilatories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_depilatory) seem to be the norm; Gilad Pellaeon continues to use a razor, but his companion evidently prefers the chemical solution:

> "I'm shaving, Lieutenant..." The boy's like one of those hyperactive little rodents on Ber de Val, all mangy hair, twitches, and zero attention span. "I need to concentrate."
>
> "Might it not be safer to use a depilatory rather than a razor, sir?"
>
> <sup>*No Prisoners* "Prologue"</sup>

Comment: Magic indeed! Is the shaving droid's process reversible? I mean, Obi-Wan goes goes from clean shaven and bald back to regular in a short amount of time.

Comment: @Thunderforge I haven't watched the arc in a while, so I don't remember if he appears re-bearded at the end or not. Considering they have the technology to alter the bone structure of his face, I can't imagine it would be difficult to stimulate the hair follicles

Comment: It doesn't have to disintegrate.  There could just be a vacuum that pulls in the hair as it is shaved off.

Comment: @Starkey I agree with you. This is probably a remnant of when early ships had no artificial gravity, and hair needed to be vacuumed immediately after the shave occurs.